# How can i replace JSON values in Redshift?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I have a JSON array in my redshift table which has `True/False/None` values. Now since JSON only accepts lower case values and don't accept `None`, I want to convert those values into lower case `true/false/null` values. Bearing in my mind my JSON array has some keys whose values also contain the name True.

**Example :**

> [{"id": 20198, "name": "True Ventures", "path": "true_ventures", "type": "Fund", "lead": False}, {"id": 324746, "name": "XXX", "path": "XXX", "type": "Investor", "url": "XXX", "image": "XXX", "lead": False}]

> [{"id": 20198, "name": "True Ventures", "path": "true_ventures", "type": "Fund", "lead": True}, {"id": 324746, "name": "XXX", "path": "XXX", "type": "Investor", "url": "XXX", "image": "XXX", "lead": True}]

> [{"id": 20198, "name": "True Ventures", "path": "true_ventures", "type": "Fund", "lead": None}, {"id": 324746, "name": "XXX", "path": "XXX", "type": "Investor", "url": "XXX", "image": "XXX", "lead": None}]

Now, I want to replace the `False/True/None` values occurrences across the entire JSON array wherever there is a `True`, `False`, `None` values. (in this case for the lead key and not the name and path of the company). I am currently using

```
case
       when column_name ilike ('%True%') then regexp_replace(replace(column_name, '\'', '"'), 'True', 'true')
       when column_name ilike ('%False%')then regexp_replace(replace(column_name, '\'', '"'), 'False', 'false')
       when column_name ilike ('%None%') then replace(replace(column_name,'\'','"'),'None','"None"')
       end as column_name
```

Please let me know what would be the right way to use the regexp_replace ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the same problem as your other question? If it is you should have posted as one question, because the answers for one wouldn't work for the other. In this case, also use `eval` but first declare variable with the name of the wrong values containing the right values, e.g. `var True = true;` (Also you should stop referring to your data as "JSON". It's not JSON.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is json-like text a few assumptions can be made - that these keywords will always follow a colon (not in a list) and that colons won't appear in a field name.  Also it is likely, but you will need to confirm, that a colon won't appear in a data value followed by one of these keywords AND that these keywords will follow a colon by only one space character.  If this is all true then the change should be straight forward to make.

Just replace ': True' with ': true'.  The same holds for the other keywords.  Your case statement is in error as it will only allow for one keyword to be replaced per row of text which isn't true for you example data.  So as an untested example of what this will look like:

```
Select replace(replace(replace(column_name, ': True', ': true'),
            ': False', ': false'),
            ': None', ': null') as column_name 
from table_name;
```

If a more general purpose approach is needed then sample data of the concerning corner-cases will be needed.